# Graph library for Polymer 1.0

Tags: graph, polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0

Does anyone know is there any good **graph library for Polymer 1.0**.

I've found few of them like:
https://github.com/the-control-group/app-chart/

or these

https://customelements.io/search/graph

But they are all made for polymer 0.5 and Polymer 0.5 and 1.0 are incompatible.

So if anyone knows anything that could help me I'd appreciate ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, let me google that for myself:

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-chart

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-chart?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=google-chart

:)

Answer (score 4):

Here's Google's own charting library:

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-chart

Comment: tnx, I've just found it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check out https://github.com/avdaredevil/highcharts-chart, it's responsive and supports realtime data.

I wrote it due to the underwhelming amount of elements in this area, plus highcharts.js is very robust.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.